# MPDF: Failed to display a mix of LTR and RTL text

Tags: php, css, right-to-left, mpdf

I have this block of code to use MPDF PHP library to convert a HTML document to PDF document, HTML document has both LTR and RTL languages:

```
    $mpdf = new mPDF;
    $content = '<div lang="he" style="direction: rtl;">רוחב: <span lang="en" style="direction: ltr; display: inline-block">483 mm (19")</span></div>';
    $mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
    $mpdf->Output();
```

The HTML version of $content displays correctly:

[image]

But in the PDF version, I get this

[image]

I have tried to apply many CSS styles but couldn't find any way to solve this. Do you have any solution? Thanks!

P/S: I don't speak Hebrew or any RTL language.

Comment: Try to set `rtl` for parent div only - `$content = '<div lang="he" style="direction: rtl;">רוחב: <span lang="en">483 mm (19")</span></div>';`

Comment: Thank you @Armen, I already tried that but the result was the same.

Comment: I just tested your code and it works for me. What mPDF version are you using?

Comment: @simon it is mPDF 6.0 (20/12/2014)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is working fine in mPDF 5.7.4.

For mPDF 6.0 you need to use [`<bdo>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/bdo) instead of the css property `direction`:

```
$content = '<div dir="rtl">רוחב: <bdo dir="ltr">483 mm (19")</bdo></div>';
```

For more information about mPDF 6.0 see [this reference](http://www.mpdf1.com/repos/example61_new_mPDF_v6-0_features.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about bdo. Learnt something new today.